# Umbraco MVC 6.05 Getting IPublishedContent object through Surface Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am developping an umbraco mvc web site and im having troubles getting currentpage info within surface controller.

Here is my scenario:

I have a products page. And there are checkboxes which filters the product list. I wrote an ajax post function which fires on checkbox change event.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/umbraco/Surface/ProductsSurface/Products',
            data: JSON.stringify({ some data }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#imgAjaxLoader").css("display", "inline");
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#imgAjaxLoader").css("display", "none");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Status != null) {                        
                } else {
                }
            }
        });
```

What i want is filter product list, reproduce product list, send this data to a template page, render this page with product list and get rendered page string, and return this string to page with Json.

This is my render razor view method :

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

But the problem is even if my template page is not inherited from umbraco, it still wants a  model inherited from render model. So i inherited from it.

This is my model :

```
public class ProductListTemplateViewModel : RenderModel
{
    //Some Properties

    public ProductListTemplateViewModel() : this(new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).TypedContent(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId)) { }
    public ProductListTemplateViewModel(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture) : base(content, culture) { }
    public ProductListTemplateViewModel(IPublishedContent content) : base(content) { }
}
```

But after i did that and render page, i ve got an error says `Value Cannot Be NULL`

That is because IPublishedContent content object is null so i have to bind this value to my view model.

```
IPublishedContent iPublishedContent = CurrentPage;
```

While executing this code nothing happens it s not stepping next code. Its like freezes there, getting into an infinite loop.

So i cannot get value. Nothing happens no error.

I am desperate now. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: If you try and access UmbracoContext.Current.PageId in your controller, is it null?